# Are relaxed data structures used in real applications?

Tags: performance, data-structures, concurrency

I am learning about concurrent data structures, and I have come across a broad research literature on **relaxed** data structures, such as k-relaxed queues, stacks, counters, etc. See, e.g., here

https://github.com/cksystemsgroup/scal#data-structures

or here

http://www.faculty.idc.ac.il/gadi/MyPapers/2015ST-RelaxedDataStructures.pdf

The idea is that a relaxed data structure offers weaker guarantees (e.g., a dequeue operation of a k-relaxed FIFO queue is free to give any of the first k elements). Ideally, the relaxed data structures offer better performance than the strict ones.

The problem is that, as far as I see, these data structures are evaluated only on some micro-benchmarks (as in the first link above), measuring only pure performance/throughput of data structure operations, and not looking at how the relaxation influences the overall application design and performance.

Have you ever used such relaxed data structures **in real applications**, or can you imagine plugging in relaxed data structures into your application to obtain performance gains? Or are those data structures a purely academic exercise?

Comment: I can see it make sense if you have a lot of items to work on and you don't really care about perfect execution order. like a server with several million requests or so. If the performance impact is big enough, that the request who gets "delayed" because it was once not picked up first does not notice it why not. Like always with performance, you have to measure those things though.

Comment: Nothing I've been tasked to write has required throughput high enough to relax my data structures, but I have known some developer friends who do work on problems that require a lot of data very quickly and they have had to make such choices in lew of any issues it may cause. So I would say it isn't only an academic exercise, but it's certainly fringe case.

Comment: also when you have multiple worker threads getting their jobs from a strict data structure you can probably switch to a relaxed one because due to the multi-threading you cannot control the order in which they are done. Though I still used strict containers because they are in the standard c++ library (I don't know of any relaxed data structures in there)

Comment: I built a focused web crawler that prioritized URLs based on the output of our machine learning system. With hundreds of concurrent requests continually adding new URLs to the priority queue, guaranteeing strict priority ordering was prohibitively expensive. What we implemented was similar in concept to a k-relaxed priority queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quick Answer

Here's a quick answer by analogy. Relaxed structures are comparable to *normal*<sup>0</sup> concurrent structures, in the same way that *normal* concurrent structures are comparable to normal non-concurrent structures.

*Most* uses of data structures in an application are the plain-jane non-current ones, either because they are not shared, or because some type of coarse-grained locking is sufficient to share them. They offer a simple API and are easy to reason about, even in the presence of concurrent access when coarse-grained locking is used. To give a specific example, you'll probably find 20 to 100 uses of plain `Map` implementations for every use `ConcurrentMap`.

That doesn't make `ConcurrentMap` useless! In the 5% of places it *is* used, there may be no real substitute, performance wise!

Similarly, you are usually going to do just find with the non-relaxed concurrent structures in those places, but there may be an additional 5% (so now 0.25% of the total `Map` use) that could benefit from the relaxed structures (at the cost of additional complexity when reasoning about the system, and possibly theoretically visible service order changes for clients).

### Long Answer

I think there are two separate implied questions here:

1. Are relaxed data structures actually faster than their non-relaxed equivalents in actual use?
2. Are related data structures actually useful in real-world applications given their weaker guarantees?

I can speak about my personal experience for both of them. I have used "relaxed structures" before I even knew thew were called relaxed structures.

## Are Relaxed Structures Actually Faster?

First, maybe you are asking if relaxed structures are actually faster than their non-relaxed equivalents?

The easy answer is "Yes, but only at the extremes of concurrent access".

Microbenchmarks already show the extremes of performance. You usually have one structure which is continually accessed (i.e., with a *duty cycle* near 100%) from multiple threads. At these extremes of contention, relaxed data structures may show an order of magnitude improvement over their non-relaxed cousins. You have to realize, however, that the *vast majority* of structures are not accessed in such a fashion. Even structures which are already using concurrent data structures (think `ConcurrentHashMap` in Java), are usually accessed rarely as a percentage of total execution time, and the use of concurrent structure is necessary more for correctness and high-sigma response time than performance<sup>1</sup>.

### Usually No

That said, just because the vast majority of structures in your application don't need higher concurrent performance, it doesn't mean that it's worthless: the few structures (if any) that *do* need it, may constitute a high percentage of total accesses. What I mean is, if you look at the code level: "How many declaration of *map objects* in my application need a fast concurrent structure?", then the answer is likely to be "not many" - but if you look at the runtime level: "How many *accesses to map objects* in my application need a fast concurrent structure?" - then the answer might be a "a lot of them". It depends if you weight by "use in code" or "use at runtime".

### Sometimes Yes

Once you start tuning a highly concurrent application, you are very likely to run into a concurrency bottleneck at some point. Even if you application is very parallel - such as processing many independent incoming requests in parallel, you'll usually want to introduce some type of shared state for caching, logging, security checks or simply because your application does have some amount of shared writable state. Whatever structure you use there may indeed suffer from high contention.

As a final point on the first question: a lot of it also depends on the hardware you use. A typical behavior of contended structure is that tend to flatline in throughput under concurrent access, regardless of the number of cores accessing the structure - i.e., the maximum throughput of this structure is X, regardless of concurrency. Often that is in fact the *best* case: you may instead reach peak throughput a moderate amount of concurrency and then total throughput drops after that.

#### It Is Hardware Dependent

The impact of this depends on your hardware. If you are on a single-socket development machine with 4 cores, then this behavior isn't too terrible. You effectively drop down to 1 core for the concurrent parts, but that still leaves 25% of the maximum power available (one core). So if the inherently concurrent part of your load is 10% of the total load, then you still achieve `1 / (0.9 + 0.1 * 4) = 0.77 = 77%` of the total throughput, despite your contention. No not a problem you'd reorganize your application over. Then may you deploy to production and you are running on a 2-socket, 18-core box and it looks like `1 / (0.9 + 0.1 / 36) = 0.22 = 22%` - i.e., you are getting less than a quarter of the ideal performance level because of your concurrency bottleneck. That is a problem.

That's with the "simple" view of concurrent scaling, where performance is constant for the contended part - in reality increased contention may decrease performance, making the performance worse.

### Summary

So the long answer then finishes in the same way as the short answer - yes, there are places in highly concurrent applications that can benefit from structures that perform better in contention, but they are small in number. You have to first remove all the places where false sharing is occurring, where you have non-contention bottlenecks, and then you'll find the places where *true sharing* occurs and may benefit.

## Can Relaxed Structures Be Used in Practice?

Absolutely, yes. This is the easy part. There are many times when you need a structure that that offers weaker guarantees than the underly structure you want. For example, if you are just going to store a bunch of objects with no duplicates, in no particular order, you might use an array/vector or a linked list or a set-like structure. Each of the choices gives some advantage over the other, at the cost of some disadvantage in other scenarios (for example, arrays allow constant-time access to any element given its index, but cannot insert elements anywhere other than the end without paying an `O(n)` cost).

You don't often find structures with *even weaker* guarantees than the existing ones, because outside of concurrency there aren't really any structures are *even faster* than the basic ones, with weaker guarantees. Try it - choose a "collection" API that has the lowest-common-denominator guarantees out of arrays, linked lists, hash tables, trees, etc. I.e., it doesn't need to have fast insertion in the middle, it doesn't offer fast search by element, it doesn't offer fast indexing, etc, etc - can you make any basic operation faster?

This scenario is very common: scan through the source code for anything you've written lately and check out how you used `List` in Java or `vector` in C++, or just plain arrays: in each case, which of the high performance operations did you actually need? Often you are just holding a collection of elements and iterating over them later - that's it!

Once you introduce the new axis of **concurrent performance** - you *can* use weaker guarantees to make a faster structure. Arrays are problematic because to preserve exact insertion order you always end up contenting on some type of shared *size* variable. Linked lists are problematic because the head/tail nodes are contended and so on.

There there is a place for weaker structures. For example, a "bad" of elements, that doesn't offer FIFO insertion/iteration order, doesn't offer fast search by equality, etc. Many uses are fine with this weakening.

### Concretely

Here are a couple of places I've *actually used* or seen used relaxed structures in high-performance concurrent systems:

- For statistics collection: high-concurrent systems processing mostly independent requests often scale well because the requests do not share much mutable data. Once you start collecting system-wide fine-grained statistics, however, you have a contention point. Usually you don't need any kind of FIFO ordering for statistics and don't need searchability (at the collect point anyway) - so the in-process statistics collector code is an obvious place where relaxed structures are useful.
- For logging: in the same way as stasitics above, many systems have a *global* logging facility, which might become a point of contention. Usually you want log messages to appear in FIFO order, since out of order messages are very confusing, but you might not care much about the order of messages from independent threads in the log, or you might know exactly which messages need to occur in-order wrt other threads. Here again relaxed structures are a natural fit.
- The general problem of processing or redistributing a high-volume stream of incoming requests. Imagine what any web-server does - it processes a large number of incoming quests. Usually those requests come from many different users and it doesn't matter if the requests are processed in the exact order they arrive. There are *some* ordering cases that do matter however - usually among requests from the same user or session (e.g., image a user who submits some change with a `POST` and then issues a `GET` to reload the page: she would expect to see the changes from the previous `POST` reflected in the `GET`). So many of the front-end structures to handle the requests would relax the usual ordering requirements for performance.

---

<sup>0</sup> By *normal* concurrent structures, I mean structures like `ConcurrentHashMap` which are designed for better performance under concurrency, but usually keep their usual ordering guarantees and so on. That is, they are made about as concurrent as possible withing the boundaries of the existing API.

<sup>1</sup> Admittedly, this glosses over the difference between *average* performance, and other "long tail" performance issues. I.e., a structure may be accessed infrequently on average, but under certain scenarios access may skyrocket and it can become a bottleneck under this particular load.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed response! Really a lot of useful info justified by the real experience.

Comment: On the difference between the average case and "long tail": what would be, in your opinion, the right way to benchmark data structures? E.g., to catch the "long tail" cases, should a structure be benchmarked for a particular app together with the set of (randomized) input scenarios, that represent particular cases of heavy load? What I don't like about micro-benchmarking is that they are application- and data-agnostic, so such kind of a performance testing is about a round cow in a vacuum.

Comment: Personally I like parameterized benchmarks. So don't just pick some type of load factor (usually 100%) or other parameters of your test (e.g., the lengths of the queue), but use a parameterized test that tests a broad range of values. This sounds like a lot of work, but once you are using a decent benchmark framework (and you should!) it almost comes for free. Then you look at a graph of the results are you can really characterize the behavior from one end of the spectrum to the other. So you can say "yeah, this performs will up to until condition X and Y, or Z occur."

Comment: ... of course, that's still a "generic" approach - but it can be _good enough_ if it covers all your production-like loads by varying the parameters. That is, if your structure performs well over a domain D that is a subset of the production or real-world domain P, then you know that it performs well, and the testing is simple and straightforward. If not you're going to need to come up with some production test cases. A typical way to do that is to try to simply record actual real world input behavior and form a test case out of that.